# Using jackson to manipulate part of a JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON object, something like:

```
{
    "myData":[1,2,3],
    "externalData1":...,
    ...
    "externalDataN":...
}
```

I want to read this JSON, update my data (lets say adding number "4") and save the JSON without knowing anything about the external data fields.

I know that for parsing I can use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` but then I will loss the data on the save. Is there a way to do that without going manually over the TreeModel?

Thanks.

Comment: jackson streaming api may work, but you still have to consume external data and write it to buffer

Comment: Using Jackson, having a POJO you can write a custom serializer and set @JsonSerialize annotation to the desired POJO property or to the POJO class if you want to modify other properties or produces a specific JSON tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json):

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray myData = (JSONArray) root.get("myData");

myData.remove(0);
myData.put(4);

System.out.println("root = " + root.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json-simple`which won't give you the data binding to a POJO, but it will still be a lot more convenient than doing the parsing your self.